# Native framework for copying file on macOS

Tags: macos, filesystems, finder

Is there a framework in macOS that I can use to programmatically copy files and get a progress bar the same as copying files from Finder? [image: copy progress]

Alternatively, I can do the copy using `cp` or filesystem APIs and use `NSProgressIndicator` to implement the progress bar.

Comment: Updated screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [copyFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/copyfile.3.html).
[Here](https://github.com/rustle/RSTLCopyOperation/blob/master/Copy/RSTLCopyOperation.m) is example of copyfile with Progress Callback.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I needed it in swift.
But great Project Parag it really help me!

Thats my Copy Function.

```
   func createCopy(of:URL, to:URL,skip:Bool) throws {

    
    if !skip {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: to.path) {
            print("\n\n   did not copy \n\(of.lastPathComponent.utf8CString) \nto \n\(to.path)\n\n")
            return
        }
    }

    
    
    //open window

    let copyStoryboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "copyProgessWindow", bundle: nil)
    self.progressWindowConrtoller =  copyStoryboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "CopyProgressWindow") as! NSWindowController
    let application = NSApplication.shared
    
    //set Up view
    let viewController = self.progressWindowConrtoller!.contentViewController as! CopyViewController

    viewController.path_copyFrom.url = of
    viewController.path_copyTo.url = to
    



    
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async{
        do{
            let bufferSize:Int = 64*1024;
            var buffer = [Int32](repeating: 0, count: Int(bufferSize))
            
            let open_source = open(of.path, O_RDONLY);
            let open_target = open(to.path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
            
            let attrSource = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: of.path)
            
            let sourceFileSize = attrSource[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64
            
            
            
            var bytes_read = 0;
            
            bytes_read = read(open_source, &buffer, bufferSize);
            
            
            while(bytes_read  > 0){
                write(open_target, &buffer, bufferSize);
                
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: to.path) {
                    
                    let attrTarget = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: to.path)
                    let targetFileSize = attrTarget[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64
                    
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        viewController.progressbar_progBar.doubleValue = self.progressProcent
                    }
                        
                    self.progressProcent = Double(targetFileSize)/Double(sourceFileSize)
                    print(self.progressProcent)

                    
                }
                bytes_read = read(open_source, &buffer, bufferSize);
            }
            // copy is done, or an error occurred
            close(open_source);
            close(open_target);
            sleep(2)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                application.abortModal()
                self.progressWindowConrtoller!.close()
            }
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
        
        
    }

    application.runModal(for: self.progressWindowConrtoller!.window!)

}
```

I have a storyboard file called 'copyProgessWindow.storyboard' and important is the storyboardID set to 'CopyProgressWindow'. and it looks like this:
[storyboardCopyProgress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXvNV.png)

Thats my ViewController for the view you see:

class CopyViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var path_copyFrom: NSPathControl!
@IBOutlet weak var path_copyTo: NSPathControl!
@IBOutlet weak var label_remaindingTime: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var progressbar_progBar: NSProgressIndicator!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}
```

}

Comment: I stumbled across this after deciding to roll my own copy/move methods since FileManager does not provide any type of progress of its operations and using FSEvents or similar doesn't work since FileManager first writes to a temporary location.  Anyway, thanks for sharing.  However, I do not see any code related to the label_remainingTime.  Wasn't sure if you realized that.